# How to preload an image on my page without blocking OnLoad event?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want my page to send a request for an image but I don't care when the image has finished downloading. This request should not block the OnLoad event from firing.

If I use inline javascript to add this image tag to the page before the page has been loaded, it seems that the browser waits until the image has finished downloading before firing OnLoad, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to make the request for the image without blocking the OnLoad event? I noticed in IE9 if I set the image element source but don't append it to the DOM, then the browser makes a non-blocking request (which actually seems like a bug since I haven't put the element in the DOM yet, some speculative download at work?). This doesn't behave the same in other browsers, though.

I also tried setting a small Timeout before appending the element but that didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot preload _and_ not block `onload`. The whole _point_ of preloading is to ensure that the image is there when the browser is told to display it. Perhaps you should think about using the document ready event instead of the onload event, where it matters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My use of the word "preload" is a bit misleading I suppose. I don't care about when the image is available, my real intention is to get the server to start doing work by making this request (it's almost a throwaway request). That's why I'm looking for a way to make the request without blocking the OnLoad event.

Comment: If you don't need it before load, why do you call it before? Try to trigger it async using setTimeout and move it down in the task que.

Comment: The reason I call it before is because the request will ultimately cause my backend to do some work, and this can happen in parallel with the page load. So the earlier I can make this throwaway request, the better, but if I block on it, then I haven't improved anything. Edit: I did try setTimeout and didn't see any immediate improvement, will play with it some more.

Comment: So instead of using an `<img>` tag, why wouldn't you just use `XMLHttpRequest` (ajax)? It's asynchronous by default.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given a thought to using "DOMContentLoaded" in place of onload? It is supported by all browsers and is already there in IE9.

And if you are targeting older versions of IE, you can use the readyState property.

I am not able to understand the whole point here, but by any chance, image element's own DOM events might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This may be useful, although I'll have to do some significant refactoring of my page to take advantage of it.